# How can i turn string into array with .split but ignore quote in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

So I'm using `.split(" ")` in js to turn a string into array by whitespaces in JS. But let's say now I have the following string: `Howdy "How are you" bro`, how can I split the string by whitespaces but ignore things inside quotes (both single and double). So I can come out with something like this:

```
[
    "Howdy",
    "\"How are you\"",
    "bro"
]
```

Comment: This can get messy quickly. What if there's only a single quote? Can quotes be escaped? What about `Foo (bar "baz) blarg"`?

Comment: I think here you have to first split the string at the " (and ') and then split the remaining strings at the space again. The challenge here is to preserve the order of the split strings then.

Comment: @cloned I can successful keep the quoted text with `str = str.split('"');`, but then while I try to split it with `(i=0;i<str.length;i++) str[i] = str[i].split(" ");`, it'll become nested array. And the space behind *Howdy* and before the quote, for example, turns into a blank value within the nested array. (Like this `"[[\"Howdy\",\"\"],[\"How\",\"are\",\"you\"],[\"\",\"bro.\"]]"`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to think about this in terms of matching rather than splitting. You can match things between quotes or words in that order with something like:

```js
let s = 'Howdy "How are you" bro'
let a = s.match(/\".+?\"|\S+/g)
console.log(a)
```

If the examples become more complicated (for example nested quotes), of course, this might require some adjustments.